# Avoid boiler plate when using threading.Thread

Tags: python

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._finished = False
        self._end = False
        self._running = False

    def run(self):
        self._running = True
        while not self._finished:
            time.sleep(0.05) 
        self._end = True

    def stop(self):
        if not self._running:
            return 

        self._finished = True
        while not self._end:
            time.sleep(0.05)
```

I wish to have a thread on which I can call run() and stop(). The stop method should wait for run to complete in an orderly manner. I also want stop to return without any issues if run hasn't even be called. How should I do this?

I create this thread in a setup() method in my test environment and run stop on it in the teardown(). However, in some tests I dont call run().

**UPDATE**

Here's my second attempt. Is it correct now?

```
import threading
import time
class MyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._finished = False

    def run(self):
        while not self._finished:
            print("*")
            time.sleep(1) 
        print("Finished Other")

    def finish(self):
        self._finished = True
        self.join()     


m = MyThread()
m.start()
print("After")
time.sleep(5)
m.finish()
print("Finished Main")
```

Comment: I have explained the concept in my answer, without pointing out the issues in your code. There are several. One obvious problem: you should not overwrite the `run()` method of `threading.Thread`. Otherwise you cannot start the thread anymore (you can overwrite it, but then store it with some other name before, such as `_run`).

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke The OP did not overwrite run, he redefined it in a subclass. The documentation explicitly states that this is allowed: https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects Overriding stop is specifically disallowed.

Comment: Doh, mixed up `run` and `start`, because OP did not mention `start()` at all in his initial example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to and should not implement this yourself. What you are looking for already exists, at least in large parts. It is, however, not called "stop". The concept you are describing is usually called "join".

Have a look at the documentation for join: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join

You write

> The stop method should wait for run to complete in an orderly manner.

Join's documentation says: *"Wait until the thread terminates."* check ✓

You write

> I also want stop to return without any issues if run hasn't even be
>   called

Join's documentation says: *"It is also an error to join() a thread before it has been started"*

So, the only thing you need to make sure is that you call `join()` only after you have started the thread via the `start()` method. That should be easy for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would you mind providing an example as I'm still confused as how I should use join and stop in my case.

Comment: Try it out, and show us what you have tried via editing your question.

Comment: I've update my question with a second attempt. Does it look correct now?

Comment: Yes, great. That was a good exercise, wasn't it? :) Note how you have established an implicit communication protocol between your main thread and the "worker thread", via the `_finished` variable. You just need to be careful with using this variable. It is fine when you *write* it only from one thread, and *read* it from another. In case you have more threads involved, you potentially need to look at locking mechanism to protect such variables from concurrent access, for preventing race conditions and deadlocks and such.

Comment: Danger: The documentation you link is for ancient Python 2, while Baz seems to use current Python 3!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: indeed, seeing his usage of `print()` suggests so. The behavior of `join()`, however, does not vary among Python 2 and 3 AFAIK. Nevertheless, I updated the URL for Py 3.4.